# How can I subset the dataframe using if without facing truth value of a series is ambiguous error?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list containing around 45 dataframes with 8 columns. Now I want to subset the dataframes based on specific values present in a particular column.
Code:

```
for z in list_dataframes:
     if(z['Segmentation']=="FAST"):
             list_fast.append(z)
```

Gives me error stating the truth value of a series is ambiguous.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this?
P.S. Another entirely different question how do you remove empty dataframes from a list of dataframes consisting both empty and non-empty dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `in` on the `values`:

```
for z in list_dataframes:
     if("FAST" in z['Segmentation'].values):
             list_fast.append(z)
```

Or wrap it all in comprehension:

```
list_fast = [z for z in list_dataframes if 'FAST' in z['Segmentation'].values]
```